# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name when closing window

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a `tk.Toplevel` class to get a date from the user. After the user clicked the date, the window is closing and the date should return to the mainprocess.
When the `tk.Toplevel` is closed I've got the date, but also an error:
`\_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!kalender.!dateentry.!toplevel"`
What did I do wrong?

```
class Kalender(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, date=''):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Fenster mittig zentrieren
        x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (100 // 2)
        y = (self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (50 // 2)
        self.grab_set()
        self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(180, 90, x, y))
        self.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
        self.title('Datum auswählen')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False) 

        self.date = None
        self.sel = StringVar()
        self.cal = DateEntry(self, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', locale='de_DE', date_pattern="dd.mm.y ",
                             textvariable=self.sel)
        self.cal.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.close_window)
        self.cal.set_date(date)
        self.cal.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E)
        self.focus_set()


    def close_window(self, e):
        self.date = self.cal.get()
        self.destroy()

    def show(self):
        self.deiconify()
        self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_window)
        self.wait_window()
        return self.date
cal = Kalender(main_window, d).show()
```

I've got the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Python 310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "B:\Python 310\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 301, in _select
    self._top_cal.withdraw()
  File "B:\Python 310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2269, in wm_withdraw
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'withdraw', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!kalender.!dateentry.!toplevel"
```

It seems, that tkinter tries to call the kalender.dateentry after it has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when the user has selected a date in the pop-up calendar, the bind function `self.close_window()` will be executed and the toplevel is destroyed (so is the `DateEntry` widget). Then `DateEntry` widget closes the pop-up calendar which raises the exception.

To fix this, you can delay the execution of `self.close_window()` a bit so that it is executed after the pop-up calendar is closed using `after()`:

```py
self.cal.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", lambda e: self.after(10, self.close_window, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this, but it seems the that the `tkcalendar` module has some trouble forcing a destroy on the parent widget through a bind on the `DateEntry` class. You can try using the `withdraw` command instead, which hides the window rather than destroying it

```py
def close_window(self, e):
    self.date = self.cal.get()
    self.withdraw()
```